# physical Movement Tracking in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone, ipad, gps, mapkit

I want to track my physical Movement through iphone within my office using my office  map.The map will show all rooms of my office.for example,if i move from administraion block to another block, i have to move one icon from administraion block to another block on the map.in other words, the icon should move as i move within office.is it possible to do in iphone SDK?any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really see how this can be done, most offices have terrible GPS reception. Thus using GPS is out of the questions, als it will not be precise enough.

You could try using bluetooth although it very limited in iOS and you would have to place bluetooth dongles every wehe.

My guess it can't be done with the precision that you need.

Comment: are u saying it is not possible for particular building map(not google map).bcos CLLocation manager may return same lat & long value within building..Am i right?

Comment: @youCanChearMe GPS accuracy is awful to start with, see http://rnr.davidlokshin.com/post/825290568 Also, the radio signal is not powerful enough to work inside buildings. Without GPS the iPhone will try to position using WiFi (in case your WiFi is in the location database, otherwise you get no updates). If WiFi even works, it has a 50-100 meters accuracy.

Comment: It's like @Jano stated, the accuracy will not get any more precies then 100 meters, at best 50 meters.

Comment: suppose if the building consists well Wi-fi, is it possible?

Comment: You can still only get the accuracy to about 50 meter.